# When to (and how to) use CQWP, DVWP with sensitive documents

Tags: content-query-web-part, data-view-web-part

We have a certain need. In a SharePoint site, sensitive documents are collected as attachments to lists that contain business task data. A group needs to see what the disposition of those documents is (ie, where are they now in the processing, etc) without being able to see the actual document.

My first thought was to use a Content Query Web Part or, perhaps, a Data View Web Part, but the problem that then appeared to me was: these people do not (and cannot) have access to the original lists. If not, then how could the web parts allow them to see a couple fields from those original lists?

Answer (score 3):

You need a custom web part that impersonates an authorized user to retrieve the metatdata of the prohibited lists.

My first thought was that you could give users access to the lists and use information rights management to stop them viewing the documents, or give them view but not open permissions, but that really only stops a user accidentally viewing the document. If they are determined they will be able to find another way of viewing it, so it doesn't really satisfy your requirement. I think custom code is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If memory serves, you can use an [out of the box web service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvclists.aspx) as a datasource, which would support your requirement.

Use SharePoint designer to create a new data view with the web service as the data source. When setting this up use a service account to authenticate rather than using the login details of the current user. Configure the data view to display only the details required and that should meet your requirements.

It's probably a lower footprint than a compiled web part.